# Lighttpd: PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN correct value

Tags: performance, lighttpd, memory

I'm running Lighttpd on 256MB RAM VPS (with low estimated traffic).

In order to optimize my server performances I decided to change these settings:

```
                    "PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN" => "1",
                    "PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS" => "20"
```

The reason why I set 1 child is that with setting there are 4 php_cgi processes:

2413 11336 /usr/bin/php-cgi
 2415  4592 /usr/bin/php-cgi
 2417 11336 /usr/bin/php-cgi
 2419 27656 /usr/bin/php-cgi

If I set 4 I get >8 children. I'm wondering why and if this is ok.
Now my webserver is very fast, because I finally don't rely on swapping so massively as before.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in this [FAQ](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/1/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#How-many-php-CGI-processes-will-lighttpd-spawn) there are three config options that control the number of mod_php processes.

- `PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN` (defaults to 1)
- `max-procs` (defaults to 4)
- `min-procs` (ignored in current releases)

The formula to caluclate the initially spawned processes looks like this:

```
no_of_procs = max-procs * ( PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN + 1)
```

This means, for every procs in `max-procs` launch `PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN` workers +1 Guardian process for each parent in `max-procs`.

Answer (score 0):

For newer lighttpd instances, you should set **PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN** to 0 and control the number of instances spawned.

This can help reduce the number of total processes running as there does not need to be extra *master* processes. However, if you are using a bytecode cache, set only 1 spawned master process and control the children below it.

Set **PHP_MAX_REQUESTS** to 500 to avoid another [potential](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/1/Docs:PerformanceFastCGI#Why-is-my-PHP-application-returning-an-error-500-from-time-to-time) problem.